# Resolution too small on Ubuntu to use ATI driver installation wizard

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, resolution

I just installed Ubuntu on a new virtual machine, and have my resolution restricted to 800x600.  I have downloaded the ATI driver installer and can execute it, however, the windows that it displays are too tall to fit my resolution.  It doesn't appear to support key strokes to advance the wizard.

How do I get around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use the drivers for your physical video card in a virtual machine.  You should install the drivers for the virtual video card.  These drivers often come in a "Virtual Machine Tools" package supplied by the virtual machine vendor.

What virtual machine software are you using?

Comment: I am using virtual box, but this is my first vm on this platform, so I am still figuring everything out.

Comment: Choose Devices : Install Guest Additions...

This will mount a virtual CD-ROM drive with the needed software.  Then just run the correct install script via sudo.

Answer (score 4):

If you hold Alt in most X window managers, you can drag the body of a window and it will move where you want. Try doing this; then you can drag the window such that the requested buttons are revealed.

Comment: This is the solution asked for.  However it is *not correct* to help installing hardware drivers in a virtual machine without noting that they will not work there.

Comment: Oh. Right. Perhaps I will read the question next time.